# Conversion between classes

Tags: c++, architecture

Let's say we have a class called A and another one called B.
and we want to have a conversion method that converts A to B.

In the software architecture point of view, which one is preferred?

1. write `A.export()`
2. write `B.import()`
3. write a converter class, i.e. `convert(A, B)` or `Convert(A)` or ...

if the language matters, I'm using C++

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It entirely depends on how you intend to use it, but in many cases, the cleanest way to do this is to implement a converting constructor:

```
class B { };
class A
{
    A(const B& b) { }
};

B b;
A a = b; //< calls converting constructor
```

(of course, you could implement a converting constructor for converting from `A` to `B`, as well)

Comment: As an addition I recommend declaring the convertion constructor as `explicit A(const B& b)`. Then you will have to call it with `A a = A(b)` but you will also eliminate the risk for nasty errors when a `B` is unintentionally converted to an `A`

Comment: @Anders:  That's true, though I don't think I've ever had a major issue caused by implicit conversion (except in C++/CLI, which doesn't count ;-P); I tend to prefer non-explicit constructors for conversion because it often makes for much cleaner code.  If the constructor is explicit, it's often more work to use than just creating a nonmember function that does the conversion.

Comment: If I wrote a non-`explicit` conversion constructor, I'd be afraid that I'd forget about it, and have a nasty bug a year or two down the line.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, decide whether a conversion between them is really natural and intuitive. In that case, you could use a constructor or a member function.

However, if the connection is not too natural, you may want to go with a separate ConversionUtils class with conversion methods or something like this. You don't want to start creating too many dependencies between classes or end up implementing n*n conversions.

It is also important to be careful with "conversion constructors", as they can be invoked without you realizing it. For example, if I have an `a` and a `b` and I write something like `a==b`, the presence of a constructor in A or B that takes the other could result in successful compilation with no warning, and possibly interesting results at runtime. I would strongly encourage you to make your constructor `explicit` in these cases.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I also got the same point.
It's completely based on the intrinsic relation between them.
For example in my case, I have two objects that store a Vertex, one is used for in-core algorithms and a DiskVertex for out-of-core manipulatios.
I think in this case, I'd better write the explicit conversion.

Comment: @Nima: If the DiskVertex is one possible representation of a Vertex, then definitely don't change Vertex. You may want to make it a disk vertex with a constructor that takes normal vertices, though I'm usually careful about that.

Answer (score 1):

If we take a short look at Java (just for information, even though you are using C++):

Say that class A is String and class B is Integer (or Double, Boolean, et c). The Java library designers have put a static method in Integer ("B") called getInteger ("import") that takes a String ("A") and produces an Integer ("B"). That would be your case 2.

On the other hand, in every class (call them "A") there is a method toString ("export") that returns a String ("B"). That would be your case 1.

So even for such basic classes, they decided to use different ways. I guess that means the same thing as @James McNellis said: it depends.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload cast operators, i.e., operator T () { .. return a T value }. Whether or not you should is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

I would use your third suggestion. A separate converter class for the conversion. This way you don't directly coupled A to B or B to A. A and B will have their own responsibilities whatever  it is.

The converter class C its responsibility is purely conversion. Each class will be responsible for a single thing which in my opinion is a good thing. I believe this is the S in the SOLID design principles (Single Responsibility principle).